# How do i get a value from Literall Control ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a code for input i want to get the value of Literal Control 
dynamically.  How do i get the value of input I have selected?

Front Code

```
<ul id="ulTest" runat="server"></ul>


Dim a As LiteralControl = New LiteralControl("<input type = ""date"" id=""start"" name=""trip-start"" value = ""2018-07-22"" min = ""2018-01-01"" max=""2018-12-31"">")
a.ID = "as"
ulTest.Controls.Add(a)

Dim tb As TextBox = (TextBox)a.FindControl("as")
ul1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(a.Text))
```

Comment: there's no value for a literal control.....

Comment: Anything possible ,How do i get the value of input i am selecting dynamically. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the value on the server side or in javascript?

Comment: I am trying to get value on the server side

Comment: How and when do you retrieve the value? Your second part of the code above does not make sense.

Comment: @Furqan695 *don't* use a Literal control when you actually want an *input*. A literal control is meant to emit a string and nothing more. It has no values, no ID

Comment: @Furqan695 first of all, you don't need that LiteralControl at all. Just add the `input` in your HTML. Second, what you actually ask is how to retrieve the value of that input when the form is submitted. If your action has a parameter named `start` you can probably just read it

Comment: @Furqan695 finally, ASP.NET MVC doesn't have *controls*. It looks like this is a question about Webforms? You can use `Request.Form` to get the values of all form inputs

Comment: @Furqan695 finally check Rick Strahl's [HTML 5 Input Types on WebForms Controls](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/dec/10/html-5-input-types-on-webforms-controls). You can emit the type attribute simply by adding it to a textbox. There's no need to use a literalc control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal control represents client-side markup that gets rendered out, and should have no expectation of being able to process posted data.  If you are writing a literal out that is a textbox, you can add that as a literal, but the only way to read the value from it is to use:

```
Request.Form("trip-start")
```

There will be no direct control representation other than to do:

```
foreach (var ctl in ulText.Controls)
{
    if (ctl is LiteralControl)
    {
       var a = (LiteralControl)ct;
       //Attempt to do something
     }
}
```

I don't believe that the value you entered will be posted back; it simply will be the original markup declaration.  Also, you can't cast this then as a textbox; an error will occur:

```
var tb = (TextBox)a.FindControl("as"); //Throws Exception
```